# DropDownList selected value on a razor view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have the following DropDownList on a View Layout page that displays languages from an SQL database.  I want the selected item of the dropdownlist to be the page current culture (originalCulture). How can I accomplish that?

For example if the page current culture (originalCulture="en") is equal to (item.language_UI="en") then the DDL selected item should be English (item.language). I know that it's easy but I'm not familiar with Razor codes. Can someone help?

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
var listLanguage = "SELECT language, language_UI FROM Languages";
var originalCulture = Convert.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);

List<SelectListItem> languagedropdownlistdata = new List<SelectListItem>();
bool isSelected = false;
foreach (var item in db.Query(listLanguage))
{
    languagedropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = item.language,
        Value = item.language_UI,
        Selected = isSelected
    });
}

}
```

And here is the DropDownList on the content page:

```
@Html.DropDownList("lang", languagedropdownlistdata
<input type="submit" value="Select" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really the "Razor" codes. It is mostly C# :)

Your `isSelected` variable seems to be `false` always.
You need to change your loop body to the following:

```
foreach (var item in db.Query(listLanguage))
{
    languagedropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = item.language,
        Value = item.language_UI,
        Selected = (item.language_UI == originalCulture)
    });
}
```

The statement `(item.language_UI == originalCulture)` would be true only if the `language_UI` propery will contain exactly the same string as `originalCulture`, therefore your code should work properly.